# Duplicates numbering in excel

Tags: duplicates, excel-2007, excel-formula, countif

I want to number the duplicates for the data which has more than 100000 rows.
I can use the countif formula =COUNTIF($B$2:$B2,B2) which gives me what I want. Since the data is huge it takes very long time to get the output. I want the faster way to do this as there are multiple calculation done in same sheet.

For example:

```
abc 1
abc 2
ab  1
c   1
c   2
c   3
```

The above countif already does this, but I want the formula which is faster than countif.
Is there any other option to get the same output?

Regards,
Prashant

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pivot table. Put the pivot table on a different sheet and it will not interfere with your data sheet.

I assume the column B has a header. Create a pivot table, drag the header of column B into the row area. Then also drag it into the values area.

Now the pivot table will show a count of all the individual values in column B. You can sort the pivot table results.

All this is really basic Excel functionality and has no relevance to programming. It is not a question for StackOverflow at all. Please read the Help and the FAQ and post your next question on the correct site.

Questions about basic Excel functionality belong at [Superuser.com](http://superuser.com), not here.

Comment: Thanks Teylyn, I am sorry I was not clear enough. I have added example of what I am looking for. pivot will just give me count of value. I am using this in vba with and it is one of the cells which gets calculated for other result.

Comment: You can set the pivot table values to deliver a sum instead of a count. This is basic Excel, no relation to programming. Get the basic functionality sorted out first. Once you know how to do it with the GUI, you can attempt doing it with VBA. But you need to have a solid understanding of how the basic functionality works, before you try to manipulate it with VBA.